# How to show ads on the homescreen of android device?

Tags: android, admob, google-ads-api

Hello guys< I am a beginner here and going to use admob first time.I have created an app that provides a background service to the user. As my app is free, So, I wants to show banner ads after a certain period on the home screen of the user's android device till my background service is active.
Is it possible to show ads on homescreen and lockscreen?

Comment: I'm sure it is, but your app will receive *very* negative feedback if you try to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is a bad practice to view ads in such a way. However, if you persist in getting your answer, here it is:

You have to define an activity to which is responsible for showing ads. Then you have to create an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) in your Background-Service which refer to that Activity and execute that Intent regularly.

However, in recent versions of Android, Google limited background services in many ways because of battery life, so in order to make your Background-Service survivable, you can attach it to a Notification.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, can I do it with IntentService and alarm manager?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you can execute your intent from there and start your ad-activity